# VBA if cell on sheet 1 matches a cell in column I on sheet 2 then?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a vba if statement to check if my cell H22 on sheet 1 matches a cell in column I on sheet 2.

can someone please show me where im going wrong? Thanks

```
    If Range("H22").Value Like Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("I1").Column Then

MsgBox "Match"

Else

MsgBox "No Match Found"

End If
```

It keeps telling me there is no match found so im guessing it cant find the matching cell value in column I on sheet 2

Comment: What's not working about the above code? I suspect that you may need to qualify the first range statement with the worksheet.

Comment: I've re-worded my answer to give you a bigger idea, it keeps telling me no match found

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("I1").Column` will return "9" always because Column `I` is the 9th column. You are comparing the value in `Range("H22")` to "9". Unless `H22` is "9" you will get "No Match Found".

Try, instead, using either the `.find` method of the `range` object or loop through your column looking for values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical example of trying to match a cell value against the values in a column:

```
Sub james()
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range
    v = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H22").Value
    Set rWhere = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I:I")
    Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No match found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Match found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if i wanted to have it recognize a match first in stead of a non match, what would i put in place of "nothing"?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check for the existence of the value then bring in a low-level lookup function with `Application.Match()` or `WorksheetFunction.Match()` and depend on whether it returns an error. Something like this should suffice.

```
If IsError(Application.Match(Range("H22").Value, Sheets("Sheet 2").Columns("I"), 0)) Then
    MsgBox "No Match Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Match"
End If
```

If you wanted to look for more than one then `Application.CountIf()` would return a number between *0* and something higher.

BTW, there is not usually a space between *Sheet* and *2*.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that you're comparing an individual cell to the entire 'I' column on Sheet 2. What you could do to fix this is use a find to see if a matching value exists. If it does then return   match.

Here's some code on how to do this, I would also define `Range("H22").Value` so that you know exactly where it is coming from.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim lEndNum As Long
Dim vFindVar As Variant



Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lEndNum = oWs.Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row

Set rSearchRng = oWs.Range("I1:I" & CStr(lEndNum))

Set vFindVar = rSearchRng.Find(Range("H22").Value)

If Not vFindVar Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox "Match"

Else

    MsgBox "No Match Found"

End If
```

End Sub

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) is documentation on the find method.